# Is it OK for an Controller Action to return void with a jQuery post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The reason I ask this question is because I don't see too many examples of it.  Basically, I have a `controller` which has an `method that returns void`.  The method is called by a `post` which is done through `jQuery`.  If the post is successful, I just update a small part of the page with some html.  I do not need anything back from the method, so it is fine and acceptable that I return void?  If not, what do you usually return from controller methods when making ajax calls?

Here is my Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddToCart(ShoppingCartItem shoppingCartItem)
{ 

_shoppingCartService.AddItem(shoppingCartUserId, shoppingCartItem);

}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("#addToCart").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var shoppingCartItem = JSON.stringify(
    {
        'Name': $('#Name').val(),
        'ProductId': $('#ProductId').val(),
        'ShortDescription': $('#ShortDescription').val(),
        'Sku': $('#Sku').val()
    });

    AddToCart(shoppingCartItem);
});

function AddToCart(shoppingCartItem) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ShoppingCart/AddToCart',
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: shoppingCartItem,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json",
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        success: function () {

            var count = parseInt($('div.item-counter').html()) + 1;
            $('div.item-counter').html(count);

        }
    });
}
```

}());

I noticed that if I my action method fails, the error function will be called and if it succeeds to success function will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Without returning anything, you wont know it is was successful.

```
return Json(new { success= true });
```

then you can check `data.success` in your success function.

Comment: Seems like even with void, if there is an error, my ajax error function is called and if not, the success function is.

Comment: I would handle the error server side and return success=false.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't return void. The response from an action must be an `ActionResult`. You *can* return something like `Content("")`, which is simply nothing, but still a type of `ActionResult`.

However, typically, you should return *something*, even if it's a simple JSON structure like: `{ "success": true }`. Regardless, you want to make sure you return a proper HTTP status, like 200, for a successful request.

Comment: I will update my post because I am returning void and it is working fine, so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: MVC is probably doing some magic to create an empty `ContentResult` or similar based on void being returned.

Comment: I just updated code, I noticed that even if I return void, if my method throws an error, the error function in the ajax call will be called and if not, the success function will.

Comment: That's due to the HTTP status code. If a 500 is returned, then the error block is called. Returning a response body at all successful or not would never trigger the error block in your AJAX call (due to the 200 status required). However, it does allow you finer grained control returning a response body, as you can indicate that while the action response returned successfully there was some other issue that didn't flat out break something. However, it's on you to manually do something with that in the *success* block.

Comment: As far as the AJAX call is concerned success or failure is all about whether the server was able to send a response or not. Period. It doesn't know or care about your individual business logic definition of "success" or "failure".

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly acceptable, however your client won't know the result of the post (This would return a 204 No Content).

At the very least, you want to make them aware.  If you don't need to pass back data, I would suggest you make the return type IHttpActionResult, then return Ok() (which would return a 200 OK).

Please read more about WebApi2 return types, here:  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

Comment: I will try that, maybe this belongs in another question, but I noticed if I specify 'json` as the `dataType`, it throws a `parseerror`, but I thought I was returnign `json` unless I am confused about `dataType`?  Why do I need to set it to `html` for it to work?  It is a bit confusing?

Comment: Check your response in Fiddler or Postman, I would suspect you have configured your api to return XML.  You must configure in App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs to return JSON by default.

Comment: This is not an api call. `_shoppingCartService.AddItem` just adds an shopping cart item to a database, it is calling `PetaPoco` behind the scenes.

Comment: Trying to do this in an MVC controller might not be the best engineering decision.  That said, you would need to have return type JsonResult, then return Json(true);.  You might also need an action filter (like this:  https://gist.github.com/jgable/1792393) to allow Json to be returned from your MVC Controller.